# Positive Semi Definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand "positive semi definite".

Is the 2x2 matrix

1  1
 1  1

positive semi definite? can you explain why when I try to do a cholesky decomp on it it fails?  Ty.

Comment: A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite iff its eigenvalues are all nonnegative. In this case, the eigenvalues are $0, 2$, so the matrix is indeed semidefinite.

Answer (score 2):

The software generally does Cholesky decomposition for positive definite matrices. Yours is just positive semidefinite.

On a practical level, do the Cholesky for 
\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1+\epsilon &1 \\
1 & 1+\epsilon
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}

numerically for some small positive $\epsilon$'s and you will discover a Cholesky for your matrix

\begin{equation*}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array} \right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array} \right)\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation*}